# Existe alguma ferramenta de modelagem para banco de dados NoSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, nosql, cassandra

Vou fazer um projeto de criação de banco de dados para uma aplicação web que utilizará o banco Cassandra. Queria saber se há alguma ferramenta que possa ajudar

Comment: Conheço esta: http://creately.com/

Comment: Use a ferramenta erwinNoSQL da www.erwin.com

Answer (score 1):

A **DataStax** mantém o *[DataStax DevCenter](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/devcenter)*, que é uma ferramenta exatamente para o que você procura.

Não encontrei nenhuma solução livre (ou *open-source*) para este recurso.

Answer (score 1):

Banco de dados NoSQL geralmente são modelados de maneira diferente da usual com bancos de dados relacionais. Você pode começar respondendo a perguntas sobre como o fluxo de dados no banco irá ser capturado. Portanto o ponto importante para modelar seu banco de dados deve ser: "Quais perguntas que eu quero fazer para meu banco de dados?"

Por exemplo: 'Quais cidades tem um estado?' ou 'Quantos habitantes tem cada estado?'

Depois que você tiver estas perguntas, você precisa criar um modelo que responda estas perguntas via o BD NoSQL Cassandra. Para modela-lo você pode utilizar o [Creately](http://creately.com/) que é uma ferramenta online para modelar bancos.

Answer (score -1):

O Grupo de Banco de Dados da UFSC está trabalhando em uma ferramenta que permite a conversão de um modelo ER para bancos NoSQL:

- brModeloNext: https://github.com/gbd-ufsc/brModelo-Official-Versions/tree/master/brModeloNext

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).